# UITableView Unwanted Cell

Tags: objective-c

I am getting an unwanted cell at the top of my `UITableView`. When I configure the cell, for testing purposes, I do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"LOL";
    }
    else {cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";}
    return cell;
}
```

I have it set to return 1 cell in 1 section. As far as cells that are coming back, I am only seeing the one that says "LOL", but there is what looks like a blank cell above.

Image attached:

[image: Table View]

**EDIT: I fixed it by deleting the entire table view and dragging a new one in.**

Comment: when instatiating your table cell, try setting 'autorelease' :
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

Comment: I'm using ARC so I am unable to.

Comment: In your IB xib file, did you happen to put a blank cell on top of the table view?

Comment: No. It started with a prototype cell but I deleted that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those kind of cases, I would mark the cells, for example, set the background colour of the cells to green, so it become obvious whether there is really an extra cell there, or some other sort of blank.

Comment: The table size is dragged all the way to the top of the view and then adjusted down by the navigationcontroller that adds the NavBar.